# UIkeyboard popup with uitextfield on top (pic included)

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uitextfield, uikeyboard

I am trying to achieve this type of effect where a barbutton is pressed and uikeyboard pops up and right above it brings a uitextfield with it. Please see image attached. Can someone point me to the right about how I can do this?
Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

1. Use `UIToolbar` or `UIActionSheet`
2. Setup a textField as an `inputAccessoryView` for the keyboard.

   ```
   UIToolbar* keyboardDoneButtonView = [[UIToolbar alloc] init];
   keyboardDoneButtonView.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlack;
   keyboardDoneButtonView.translucent = YES;
   keyboardDoneButtonView.tintColor = nil;
   [keyboardDoneButtonView sizeToFit];
   UITextField *textField = [[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(30, 10, 260, 30)];
   [keyboardDoneButtonView setItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:textField, nil]];

   masterTextField.inputAccessoryView = keyboardDoneButtonView;

   // where masterTextField is the textField is the one you tap, and the keyboard rises up along with the small textField.

   masterTextField.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDone;

   [masterTextField setKeyboardType:UIKeyboardTypeDefault];
   ```

**update:**

For a button, put the above code in the (IBAction) of the button.
 And instead of masterTextField, create a UIView and add it as a SubView to your view.

Comment: How can I set a UIBarButtoonItem's inputAccessoryView? there's no such method.

Comment: thanks for the reply. I don't want a master text field, just want a button that you click and keyboard rises up with textfield